# Fill middle-bottom with content on a background image

Tags: html, css, css-frameworks

I would do the following:
I have a background image (top center) and I would fill its middle-bottom with content. I would do something like http://glocalventures.org/ . Note: it's resizable!

How can I make something like this? I use Zurb Foundation as CSS Framework.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**I am not really sure what you are asking here. I am assuming you are talking about making a background-image similar to this site?**

**To control your background-image / background position via CSS. You can do something like this:**

```
body {
background-image:url(../images/bg.jpg);
background-position: top center ;
background-repeat:none;
}
```

**or you can use pixels**

```
body {
background-image:url(../images/bg.jpg);
background-position: 100px 100px ;
background-repeat:none;
}
```

**or if you want percentages**

```
body {
background-image:url(../images/bg.jpg);
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat:none;
}
```

**to make it resizable you can use this CSS property:**

```
background-size:100% 100%;
```

****Note This is a CSS3 property and will not work in some older browsers.***

If this isn't what you are looking for. You can right click on their site view their CSS via source code and see how they are doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Set the image to top, centre:

```
yourImage{
   background: #ffffff url(../images/bg.jpg) top center no-repeat;
}
```

Set where the text goes:

```
yourText{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

and the HTML code for this:

```
<div id="yourImage">
    <p id="yourText">some text...</p>
</div>
```